# Custom print preview in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im developing an Chrome Extension which need to customize the print preview dialog (to count pages, to realtime on/off images and font size changing).

Is there any way to insert javascript into chrome print preview? Or, may be, how to create my own preview with page-splitting and other print preview attributes?

Comment: I need to make hyperlinks not clickable in print preview in Chrome and am not having any luck finding out anyway to do that.